# Having hard time querying database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data in mysql using php I have FK with parishionerID
my query is correct but I always get the **Error querying database**. It doesn't show me
the specific query that I'm having an error with. BapID is PK. Hope you can help me resolve this. Thanks.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'RMS') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
$sql="INSERT INTO baptismal (ParishionerID, BapID, Datebaptism, Ministerbaptism, Sponsor, Sponsor2, Volume, Page)

VALUES('$id', NULL, '$Datebap', '$Ministerbap', '$Sponsor', '$Sponsor2, '$Volume', '$Page')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($con);
```

#### If I input datas in mysql manually this is the query which is pretty have the same with my query.

```
INSERT INTO `rms`.`baptismal` (`ParishionerID`, `BapID`, `Datebaptism`, `Ministerbaptism`, `Sponsor`, `Sponsor2`, `Volume`, `Page`) VALUES ('80', NULL, '2014-07-16', '131', 'sdasd', '123123', '123123', '123');
```

Comment: There is a function to know what goes wrong : http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: It doesn't show you the specific error because you're not telling it to. If mysqli_query fails, you should use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to retrieve the detailed error description. Also, your query may be failing because you're not using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which would insulate you from problems in your data. (What if $Sponsor was "Michael O'Reilly", for example? That adds an extra quote into your SQL statement, which now fails. Prepared statements will escape parameters automatically.)

Comment: thanks for your replies.
@MattGibson now that you mention about that I think I should fix that up. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be only Syntax error. Youre missing `'`

```
VALUES('$id', NULL, '$Datebap', '$Ministerbap', '$Sponsor', '$Sponsor2, '$Volume', '$Page')";
----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks i've been trying to figure out why my code doesn't work only to find out that its because of a single quote. i feel stupid now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your **$Sponsor2** is not properly quoted.

FYI: Let the script print out the error SQL too.
Convert your line as:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error querying database: '.$sql);
```

Then, you will see the exact query that ran.
Do not print SQLs on the server mode.